# How to add chart in pageheader by JasperReports java API?

Tags: java, jasper-reports

At first, I create a chart, and set a `CustomizerClass` to it. I use `setNoDataMessage` in the `customizerClass` to check that if any data is selected from database. The chart works fine in summary, but the `NoDataMessage` shows up when I put the chart in pageheader.

Does anyone have any ideas on this problem?

PS. The chart also works fine in footer、detail. The `NoDataMessage` shows up in title、pageheader、columnheader.

The jrxml file, exported by  `JasperReports java API`, is shown below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="Sample3Report" pageWidth="700" pageHeight="3000" whenNoDataType="AllSectionsNoDetail" columnWidth="562" leftMargin="30" rightMargin="20" topMargin="30" bottomMargin="30" isTitleNewPage="true" isSummaryNewPage="true">
    <style name="titleStyle" isDefault="true" forecolor="#000000" fontName="Helvetica" fontSize="20" isBold="true" isItalic="false" isUnderline="false" isStrikeThrough="false" isPdfEmbedded="true"/>
    <style name="headerStyle" isDefault="true" forecolor="#FFFFFF" backcolor="#808080" fontName="Helvetica" fontSize="12" isBold="true" isItalic="false" isUnderline="false" isStrikeThrough="false" isPdfEmbedded="true"/>
    <style name="detailStyle" isDefault="true" forecolor="#000000" fontName="Helvetica" fontSize="12" isBold="false" isItalic="false" isUnderline="false" isStrikeThrough="false" isPdfEmbedded="true"/>
    <style name="pageheaderStyle" isDefault="true" forecolor="#000000" fontName="Helvetica" fontSize="10" isItalic="false" isUnderline="false" isStrikeThrough="false" isPdfEmbedded="true"/>
    <parameter name="IMAGE" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[select p.personid as personId, p.name as personName, p.age as personAge, c.carid as carId, c.model as carModel, c.color as carColor, c.price as carPrice from person p join car c on p.personid=c.ownerid order by personName]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="personName" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="personAge" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
    <field name="carModel" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="carColor" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="carPrice" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
    <title>
        <band height="700">
            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement key="titleTextField" style="titleStyle" positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" mode="Opaque" x="0" y="250" width="600" height="300"/>
                <box padding="1">
                    <pen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center"/>
                <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA["Cars report"+"\n\n.subtitle"+"\n\n.writer"]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </title>
    <pageHeader>
        <band height="500">
            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" evaluationTime="Auto" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement key="titleTextField" style="detailStyle" positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" mode="Opaque" x="570" y="0" width="600" height="14"/>
                <box padding="1">
                    <pen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Left"/>
                <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA["Cars table"]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <image>
                <reportElement x="540" y="0" width="30" height="30"/>
                <imageExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA["http://static4.depositphotos.com/1029305/388/v/950/depositphotos_3889034-Stylized-cartoon-car.jpg"]]></imageExpression>
            </image>
            <areaChart>
                <chart customizerClass="customizer.AreaChartCustomizer">
                    <reportElement x="0" y="100" width="350" height="200"/>
                    <chartTitle>
                        <titleExpression><![CDATA["chart1. line chart of portA"]]></titleExpression>
                    </chartTitle>
                    <chartSubtitle/>
                    <chartLegend/>
                </chart>
                <categoryDataset>
                    <categorySeries>
                        <seriesExpression><![CDATA["test"]]></seriesExpression>
                        <categoryExpression><![CDATA[$F{carModel}]]></categoryExpression>
                        <valueExpression><![CDATA[$F{carPrice}]]></valueExpression>
                    </categorySeries>
                </categoryDataset>
                <areaPlot>
                    <plot/>
                    <categoryAxisFormat>
                        <axisFormat>
                            <labelFont/>
                            <tickLabelFont/>
                        </axisFormat>
                    </categoryAxisFormat>
                    <valueAxisFormat>
                        <axisFormat>
                            <labelFont/>
                            <tickLabelFont/>
                        </axisFormat>
                    </valueAxisFormat>
                </areaPlot>
            </areaChart>
        </band>
    </pageHeader>
    <columnHeader>
        <band height="12">
            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement key="headerField1" style="headerStyle" positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" mode="Opaque" x="0" y="0" width="150" height="12"/>
                <box padding="2">
                    <pen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center"/>
                <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA["Owner name"]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement key="headerField2" style="headerStyle" positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" mode="Opaque" x="150" y="0" width="100" height="12"/>
                <box padding="2">
                    <pen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center"/>
                <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA["Owner age"]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement key="headerField3" style="headerStyle" positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" mode="Opaque" x="250" y="0" width="150" height="12"/>
                <box padding="2">
                    <pen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center"/>
                <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA["Car model"]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement key="headerField4" style="headerStyle" positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" mode="Opaque" x="400" y="0" width="100" height="12"/>
                <box padding="2">
                    <pen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center"/>
                <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA["Car color"]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement key="headerField5" style="headerStyle" positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" mode="Opaque" x="500" y="0" width="100" height="12"/>
                <box padding="2">
                    <pen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center"/>
                <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA["Car price"]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </columnHeader>
    <detail>
        <band height="12">
            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement key="detailField1" style="detailStyle" positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" mode="Opaque" x="0" y="0" width="150" height="12"/>
                <box padding="2">
                    <pen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Left"/>
                <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$F{personName}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement key="detailField2" style="detailStyle" positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" mode="Opaque" x="150" y="0" width="100" height="12"/>
                <box padding="2">
                    <pen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right"/>
                <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.Integer"><![CDATA[$F{personAge}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement key="detailField3" style="detailStyle" positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" mode="Opaque" x="250" y="0" width="150" height="12"/>
                <box padding="2">
                    <pen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Left"/>
                <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$F{carModel}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement key="detailField4" style="detailStyle" positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" mode="Opaque" x="400" y="0" width="100" height="12"/>
                <box padding="2">
                    <pen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Left"/>
                <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$F{carColor}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement key="detailField5" style="detailStyle" positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" mode="Opaque" x="500" y="0" width="100" height="12"/>
                <box padding="2">
                    <pen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Left"/>
                <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.Integer"><![CDATA[$F{carPrice}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </detail>
    <pageFooter>
        <band height="50">
            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement key="titleTextField" style="pageheaderStyle" positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" mode="Opaque" x="30" y="0" width="600" height="14"/>
                <box padding="1">
                    <pen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Left"/>
                <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA["Cars table"]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <image>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="50" height="50"/>
                <imageExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$P{IMAGE}]]></imageExpression>
            </image>
        </band>
    </pageFooter>
    <summary>
        <band height="700">
            <lineChart>
                <chart isShowLegend="true">
                    <reportElement x="0" y="300" width="350" height="200"/>
                    <chartTitle>
                        <titleExpression><![CDATA["chart2. line chart of portB"]]></titleExpression>
                    </chartTitle>
                    <chartSubtitle/>
                    <chartLegend textColor="#FFFF00" backgroundColor="#0000FF"/>
                </chart>
                <categoryDataset>
                    <categorySeries>
                        <seriesExpression><![CDATA["test"]]></seriesExpression>
                        <categoryExpression><![CDATA[$F{carModel}]]></categoryExpression>
                        <valueExpression><![CDATA[$F{carPrice}]]></valueExpression>
                    </categorySeries>
                </categoryDataset>
                <linePlot>
                    <plot/>
                    <categoryAxisFormat>
                        <axisFormat>
                            <labelFont/>
                            <tickLabelFont/>
                        </axisFormat>
                    </categoryAxisFormat>
                    <valueAxisFormat>
                        <axisFormat>
                            <labelFont/>
                            <tickLabelFont/>
                        </axisFormat>
                    </valueAxisFormat>
                </linePlot>
            </lineChart>
            <areaChart>
                <chart customizerClass="customizer.AreaChartCustomizer">
                    <reportElement x="0" y="100" width="350" height="200"/>
                    <chartTitle>
                        <titleExpression><![CDATA["chart1. line chart of portA"]]></titleExpression>
                    </chartTitle>
                    <chartSubtitle/>
                    <chartLegend/>
                </chart>
                <categoryDataset>
                    <categorySeries>
                        <seriesExpression><![CDATA["test"]]></seriesExpression>
                        <categoryExpression><![CDATA[$F{carModel}]]></categoryExpression>
                        <valueExpression><![CDATA[$F{carPrice}]]></valueExpression>
                    </categorySeries>
                </categoryDataset>
                <areaPlot>
                    <plot/>
                    <categoryAxisFormat>
                        <axisFormat>
                            <labelFont/>
                            <tickLabelFont/>
                        </axisFormat>
                    </categoryAxisFormat>
                    <valueAxisFormat>
                        <axisFormat>
                            <labelFont/>
                            <tickLabelFont/>
                        </axisFormat>
                    </valueAxisFormat>
                </areaPlot>
            </areaChart>
            <multiAxisChart>
                <chart customizerClass="customizer.MultiAxisOrderCustomizer">
                    <reportElement x="0" y="500" width="350" height="200"/>
                    <chartTitle/>
                    <chartSubtitle/>
                    <chartLegend/>
                </chart>
                <multiAxisPlot>
                    <plot/>
                    <axis>
                        <areaChart>
                            <chart customizerClass="customizer.AreaChartCustomizer">
                                <reportElement x="0" y="100" width="350" height="200" backcolor="#FFFFFF"/>
                                <chartTitle color="#000000"/>
                                <chartSubtitle color="#000000"/>
                                <chartLegend textColor="#000000" backgroundColor="#FFFFFF"/>
                            </chart>
                            <categoryDataset>
                                <categorySeries>
                                    <seriesExpression><![CDATA["test"]]></seriesExpression>
                                    <categoryExpression><![CDATA[$F{carModel}]]></categoryExpression>
                                    <valueExpression><![CDATA[$F{carPrice}]]></valueExpression>
                                </categorySeries>
                            </categoryDataset>
                            <areaPlot>
                                <plot/>
                                <categoryAxisFormat>
                                    <axisFormat>
                                        <labelFont/>
                                        <tickLabelFont/>
                                    </axisFormat>
                                </categoryAxisFormat>
                                <valueAxisFormat>
                                    <axisFormat>
                                        <labelFont/>
                                        <tickLabelFont/>
                                    </axisFormat>
                                </valueAxisFormat>
                            </areaPlot>
                        </areaChart>
                    </axis>
                    <axis>
                        <lineChart>
                            <chart>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="300" width="350" height="200" backcolor="#FFFFFF"/>
                                <chartTitle color="#000000"/>
                                <chartSubtitle color="#000000"/>
                                <chartLegend textColor="#000000" backgroundColor="#FFFFFF"/>
                            </chart>
                            <categoryDataset>
                                <categorySeries>
                                    <seriesExpression><![CDATA["test"]]></seriesExpression>
                                    <categoryExpression><![CDATA[$F{carModel}]]></categoryExpression>
                                    <valueExpression><![CDATA[$F{carPrice}]]></valueExpression>
                                </categorySeries>
                            </categoryDataset>
                            <linePlot>
                                <plot/>
                                <categoryAxisFormat>
                                    <axisFormat>
                                        <labelFont/>
                                        <tickLabelFont/>
                                    </axisFormat>
                                </categoryAxisFormat>
                                <valueAxisFormat>
                                    <axisFormat>
                                        <labelFont/>
                                        <tickLabelFont/>
                                    </axisFormat>
                                </valueAxisFormat>
                            </linePlot>
                        </lineChart>
                    </axis>
                </multiAxisPlot>
            </multiAxisChart>
        </band>
    </summary>
</jasperReport>
```

Comment: Post some example of jrxml used

Comment: When I put the area chart in the pageheader, the NoDataMessage shows up. But it works fine in summary tag.

Comment: Need to test it but the problem is probably related to datasource, summary band is executed once after detail band, the pageHeader mulitple times.. when detail band is running, considering that you have only one datasource, I believe it can not reset it and run it while you are running it in detail band.